# Problem with list-packages, package menu. Command / / removes my install I mark?

Tags: list-packages

I do `M-x list-packages`. I want to install several packages, the first is beeminder. So I type `/ n beeminder RET` to display the beeminder package.  Great, I type `i` and it's marked for installation.  Then `/ /` to get back to the main list because I want to hunt for a couple more packages.  But now, beeminder is no longer marked for installation!

I should think that `/ /` should only affect my view, i.e. what is filtered or not filtered, and not remove the `I` install designation. Am I wrong?

GNU emacs 27.2

Comment: I can confirm this happens to me too. Is this a bug? I personally would expect like you that `/ /` only clears the filter but not the install mark...

Comment: @halloleo What version of emacs and org mode are you using?

Comment: Emacs 27.2 without org mode.